How to solve the problem 'User memory limit exceeded' in supervised classification?
I'm trying to do supervised classification on google earth engine. I haven't done a lot of supervised classifications on gee but system keep saying:

User memory limit exceeded.

How can I solve this problem?
Here are my codes:
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_TOA')
    .filterDate('2024-01-01','2024-08-01')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5);
     
     
var median =image.reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(roi);
Map.addLayer (median,{bands:['B4_median','B3_median','B2_median'], max:0.3}, 'image_rgb')

Map.setCenter ( 41.871554, 26.776349 )

var newfc= water.merge(buildup).merge(agriculture).merge(forest);
var bands = ['B2_median','B3_median','B4_median','B5_median'];
var training =median.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection : newfc,
  properties :['LC'],
  scale: 30,
});

var random_column = training.randomColumn('random');
var training_sample = random_column.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',0.7));
var validation_sample = random_column.filter(ee.Filter.lte('random',0.7));


var classifier_rf = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features:training_sample,  
  classProperty:'LC',
  inputProperties: bands
  }).setOutputMode('classification')

  var classified_rf = median.select(bands).classify(classifier_rf);
 Map.addLayer (classified_rf, {min:1, max:4, palette : ['00ffff','ff0000','00ff04','008800']}, 'RF_classification'); 
 
 var classifier_svm = ee.Classifier.libsvm();
 var trained = classifier_svm.train(training_sample, 'LC', bands).setOutputMode('classification')
 var classified_svm = median.classify(trained);
 Map.addLayer (classified_svm, {min:1, max:4, palette : ['00ffff','ff0000','00ff04','008800']}, 'SWM_classification');
 
 
 var classified_1 = validation_sample.classify(trained);
 var error_matrix_1 = classified_1.errorMatrix({
  actual:'LC', 
  predicted:'classification', 
 });
 
 var total_accuracy = error_matrix_1.accuracy();
 print(total_accuracy);
 var user_accuracy = error_matrix_1.producersAccuracy()
  print(user_accuracy, 'User_accuracy_svm');
  var prducer_accuracy = error_matrix_1.producersAccuracy()
  print(prducer_accuracy, 'Producer_accuracy_svm');
  var kappa = error_matrix_1.kappa()
  print(kappa,'kappa_svm');


You have to share your complete script. Use the Get Link button in the EE Code Editor and make sure any assets used are shared. How much training data you have will of course impact the amount of memory you need, and that is impossible to determine from the snippet you included here.
